# alguien sabe como ejecutar ese bloque anónimo, estoy usando la clase pdo

Tags: pdo, plsql

```
<?php
    require_once("../DB/conexion.php");

    class modeloTipoContrato{

        function consultarTipoContrato()
        {
            $con=Conexion::getConexion();
            $sql='BEGIN :res:=IPS$_SNDTIPOCONTRATO.FN_CONSULTARTIPOCONTRATO(); END;';
            $sentencia=$con->prepare($sql);
            $sentencia->bindParam(":res",$resultado,PDO::ATTR_CURSOR|PDO::CURSOR_SCROLL);
            $sentencia->execute();

            $resultado=$sentencia->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
            var_dump($resultado);
            
        }
    }
    $modelo=new modeloTipoContrato();
    $modelo->consultarTipoContrato();

?>
```

Comment: ¿A qué te refieres con *bloque anónimo*? ¿Qué representa `:res` en tu código? Debes saber que las consultas preparadas son para sustituir valores relativos a columnas, no nombres de tablas, columnas, funciones, etc. Por favor, explica en la pregunta qué es lo que quieres hacer/lograr.

Comment: mm como te explico ese bloque sql devuelve un cursor, la idea es almacenar ese cursor en la variable "rest" pero no se como decirle al pdo que una variable out la cual debe almacenar ese cursor que viene siendo un array

Comment: Me parece que no es posible almacenar *cursores*. Cuando el método retorna la conexión se cierra y el *cursor* no sería accesible con la conexión que lo abrió cerrada. Lo que se suele hacer es guardar los datos en variables y retornar esas variables.

Answer (score 0):

Esperando sea de utilidad:

```
public function getDisponible($strCombinacion,$periodo,$tipoPeriodo,$adapter) {

        $strSQL = "select (xxget_api.obtiene_disponible (";
        $strSQL = $strSQL . "p_combinacion =>'" . $strCombinacion . "',";
        $strSQL = $strSQL . "p_periodo =>'" . $periodo . "',";
        $strSQL = $strSQL . "p_al_periodo =>'" . $tipoPeriodo . "')) as DISPONIBLE ";
        $strSQL = $strSQL . "from dual";
        $query=$adapter->query($strSQL);
        $query->execute();
        $resulSet=null;
        $resulSet = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        return $resulSet;
    }
```

Comment: Hola! Bienvenido. Recuerda siempre incluir una breve explicación de por qué tu código resuelve el problema. Cómo se debe usar? Cómo cambia lo que tiene quien pregunta?